# Activity never becomes requested state "[DESTROYED, RESUMED, STARTED, CREATED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")

Tags: android, android-espresso, xiaomi

This is not a duplicate question.
I have already looked at similar questions. I have added the questions I have referred to at the last.

My problem is that the test executes, but I have to open the app manually for every test.

[image: screenshot]

You can see that I had been waiting for 18 seconds before opening the app. It waits till I open the app manually or it shows this error after a timeout.

> Activity never becomes requested state "[DESTROYED, RESUMED, STARTED, CREATED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458330/android-instrumented-test-throws-exception-activity-never-becomes-requested-sta), I assume the issue is with the device as I am using `Redmi Note 5`.
I have `disabled animations` as well as the `MIUI optimization` option.

Any help is appreciated to run the tests on Xiaomi devices automatically.

No point in running automated UI tests manually.

**Update 1**
It executes only for launcher / main activity.
It is not working for other activities.

**Update 2**
I also happen to have a Redmi 4. The tests work on that device as expected without any code changes.

**Referred SO questions**

- [AndroidX.Test ActivityScenario: java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED]" (last lifecycle transition = "STOPPED")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53598321/9636037)
- [Android device doesn't launch activities on the screen while espresso testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477001/android-device-doesnt-launch-activities-on-the-screen-while-espresso-testing)
- [Activity never becomes requested state in UI Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083769/activity-never-becomes-requested-state-in-ui-testing)
- [java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62952309/java-lang-assertionerror-activity-never-becomes-requested-state)
- [Android instrumented test throws exception: Activity never becomes requested state "[RESUMED, DESTROYED, STARTED, CREATED]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458330/android-instrumented-test-throws-exception-activity-never-becomes-requested-sta)
- [How do I fix this error java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[DESTROYED]" (last lifecycle transition = "RESUMED")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67537197/how-do-i-fix-this-error-java-lang-assertionerror-activity-never-becomes-request)

**And related issues,**

- https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/143
- https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/496

Adding code snippets and dependencies for anyone who wants to have a look,

**Test code**

```
import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class MainActivityTest {
    @Test
    fun test_isActivityInView() {
        val activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
        onView(withId(R.id.layout_activity_main)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.4.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.4.0"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
```

Comment: The same problem is happening on Readmi 4.

Comment: @HarisDautović,
I have a Redmi 4 as well and it works on that device for me.

Comment: Faced similar issue in Jetpack Compose testing as well - This helped for that - https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/1199#issuecomment-1003197518

Answer (score 23):

This is a problem of permissions. Just allow **autostart** and **pop-up window** for this app on your android phone settings.

Then start USB debugging and allow **chain-start** for the test app.

It worked for me on XiaoMi 11 青春版.

You can find these settings on Settings->Apps->Manage Apps
->Your-Application->Permissions

Comment: It worked for me! Although the test that manually passed now automatically don't. hahahaha

Comment: Wasted 2 hours on this, really glad this worked.

Comment: wasted 4 hours on this, really glad this worked, thanks mate :)

Comment: Wasted my entire life on this. Really glad this worked... Thanks mate!

Comment: Still wasting time and can not fix this... What is Autostart and Popup Window?

Comment: Legend says that time is still being wasted on this.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem.
The problem sometimes arises because of using

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.6'
```

instead of

```
debugImplementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.3.6'
```

If you have fragments in your test scenarios add this dependency with `debugImplementation` and check it again.
Thanks to [this post](https://forums.raywenderlich.com/t/problem-with-testing-fragments-in-androidx/58035/3?u=mansoorexpert) for the answer.

Comment: Changing to debugImplementation , Worked for me thank you

Answer (score 5):

I was getting following error on my Android 11 device

java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[STARTED, RESUMED, CREATED, DESTROYED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PRE_ON_CREATE")

I wasted a good amount of time on it and found the solution when I switched my device to Android 10.

If anybody facing such issue, please do following things to resolve it,

1. Enable autostart in app setting
2. Grant the permission to "Display pop_up windows while running in the background" from app permission settings

Answer (score 1):

I was testing in a virtual Pixel 2 with API 30. No option for "autostart" or "pop-up" in Settings. In short, what this message says is that can't open the activity, so if you open manually your app, either in virtual device or real one, the test will run.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I tested Compose fragment as well as usual fragments. I [added libraries](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing):

```
androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.6.0")
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.6.0")
```

In a test I added rules:

```
@get:Rule
val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, true, false)

@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()
```

Then started the test:

```
@Before
open fun setUp() {
    activityRule.launchActivity(null)
}
```

And got this exception: "java.lang.AssertionError: Activity never becomes requested state "[DESTROYED]" (last lifecycle transition = "PAUSED")".

Then I replaced one rule with:

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()
```

At least, it launches an app, will test later.

Comment: I' have the same issue. Did you find a solution for that?

Comment: @dudi, yes, `@get:Rule val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()` `@get:Rule val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, true, false)`. Please, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77990492/2914140.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had an update awaiting me on my Android 11 Redmi Note 10s, after updating and doing the other suggested answers it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you call `getIntent().setAction()` on the `onCreate` method and remove it if so.

That's how I "solved" it in my case.