# JetPack Compose Instrumented Test No compose hierarchies found in the app

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm following this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-write-automated-tests?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-2-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-write-automated-tests#4

and implementing the code I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No compose hierarchies found in the app. Possible reasons include: (1) the Activity that calls setContent did not launch; (2) setContent was not called; (3) setContent was called before the ComposeTestRule ran. If setContent is called by the Activity, make sure the Activity is launched after the ComposeTestRule runs
```

the test code is:

```kotlin
package com.example.tiptime

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.test.junit4.createComposeRule
import androidx.compose.ui.test.onNodeWithText
import androidx.compose.ui.test.performTextInput
import com.example.tiptime.ui.theme.TipTimeTheme
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import java.text.NumberFormat

class TipUITests {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun calculate_20_percent_tip() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            TipTimeTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    TipTimeLayout()
                }
            }
        }
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Bill Amount").performTextInput("10")
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Tip Percentage").performTextInput("20")

        val expectedTip = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(2)
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText(
            "Tip Amount: $expectedTip"
        ).assertExists("No node with this text was found.")
    }
}
```

app code is: https://github.com/alghe-global/Kotlin/blob/775bb521ec35c93753c7c5579067fdb4a1b4f742/AndroidBasicsCourse/TipTime/app/src/main/java/com/example/tiptime/MainActivity.kt

how can I debug these three statements?

```
(1) the Activity that calls setContent did not launch; (2) setContent was not called; (3) setContent was called before the ComposeTestRule ran
```

Comment: Well, I took a week break from this and coming back to it it seems the issue disappeared altogether. The test runs successfully on both an Android device and an emulator.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had:

```
@get:Rule
val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, true, false)

@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()
```

and got this exception.

Then I *swapped* these two rules (from [the link](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/2750060/when-using-createemptycomposerule-and-launching-the-activity)).